Frame prehung door at an angle between two perpendicular walls where width is tight
This is in my bathroom and the 28" prehung door is for the toilet closet.
Wall 1 is the shower wall. So instead of drywall, it ends with the metal trim.
Wall 2 is the vanity wall, which I can make it longer if needed.

Questions: How do I frame the prehung door in between the two walls?
I was looking at this page https://www.diychatroom.com/threads/framing-an-angled-wall.5745/

I don't believe I have space to add 1.5" stud on both left and right side of the prehung lamb.
Few options I am thinking:
Option 1: Use thinner stud such as 1" instead of standard 2x4 (1.5")
Option 2: Push the door inward a bit (somewhat like the diagram I had above), then frame the U shape inside?! Not sure.

Then pull the walls back a bit, making the opening wider. It's an isosceles right triangle; determining where to put the corners to obtain a given hypotenuse length (prehung door and the framing to support it) should be straightforward.

@keshlam I think only one wall could be pulled back, given the OP says Wall 1 is the shower (presumably tiled), and trimmed in metal.  OP, I'm not sure how making Wall 2 longer would help...I'd think it would make your opening width narrower.

@Huesmann: true. It's still a right triangle, so the math given a required hypotenuse length should still be straightforward. If in doubt, make it a bit wider and then shim in as necessary.

@keshlam yeah, just pointing out that shortening one wall will change the angle from 45º to something else, but I doubt it'd make enough of a difference in terms of length or angular tolerance, given that drywall will go on top of it anyway.

A 28" door needs a 30" opening. You need about 3 inches (2 studs) on either side of the door for trim placement. So you need the opening between the 2 closest wall edges to be 36".  If you cannot get that dimension, switch to a 24" door. Then you need 32" minimum.
You could reduce the minimum distance between the walls by 1 1/2" by using a stud (1 1/2 ") and a 1x4 (3/4") on each side. 34 1/2" for your 28" door or 30 1/2" for the 24 " door.  This will get you just enough room for trim.  (However If you are cutting back one wall, why not do it to fit the proper 2 studs on each side of the door.)
If you don't give yourself that much room, you will have issues with finish trim.  The stud cut as shown in your pic is great. Just get room to fit everything.

perhaps you can do this to reduce the amount of angled wall?

That is trim a 45 wedge degree off the back of the studs that accept the door jamb.
you still have 2 full studs supporting the door jamb and no-longer have a short bottom plate, just mitre the end. if the header could be interesting but if you double mitre the ends it can rest on  most of two studs. if you need that much support.

trim, well that's going to be tricky


Could you elaborate or annotate this diagram? Sorry I don't quite follow.
